# Android BLE "Write Long Characteristic Value"

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I need to write an Android App to communicate with a BLE GATT server device. I need the app to implement the "Write Long Characteristic Value" procedure as specified in the Core Bluetooth 4.2 Specification (Vol. 3 Part G), and I would like to know if the Android Bluetooth stack implements this procedure or if there is any library that could help. I've been searching the documentation and found nothing about this specific subject. On Linux I have implemented a python script with pygatt (GATTTool Backend) and it works perfectly, so I would assume Android should be able to do it too.

I also tested with nRF app from Nordic, but when trying to send a message longer than the MTU size the app crops the data instead of using the prepare write for the chunks and the write executive at the end. I'm assuming this is a limitation of the app and not the BLE stack on Android, and that's why I'm thinking of implementing my own app.

Any information would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android supports long writes out of the box. Just do a normal write and under the hood Android will break it up. So as long as the GATT server can handle it, it should work.

Comment: Hi!, Thanks for your answer! While testing with the nRF App from Nordic, I can now see from the server side that the message is correctly being broken into chunks and sent with "prepare write requests", but when the data reaches 600 bytes the "execute write request" is sent cropping the data to 600 bytes (it should be 2k). So I guess this is a limitation off the App, and Android does support the long writes like you say.

Comment: The maximum length of a characteristic is 512 bytes. so that is also the maximum you can send in a long write.

Comment: yes I've seen the "max attribute size" on the BT spec is 512 bytes, but on Linux I'm able to send 3k bytes or more without issue, and right now like I said Android using nRF app is working up to 600 bytes, so it seems weird, if they are going to enforce the limit they should stick to 512, not 600 bytes... I'll try to make a test app and see for my self. It also seems weird there is almost no documentation from the Android sdk people... anyway thanks for your feedback.

Comment: As of Android 14, 512 is enforced and 600 is no longer working. You say it works on Linux up to 3K….I never tried but that would violate the BLE spec.